# How to execute .wls as a web call through Windows IIS

Tags: scripting

If I have a simple test.wls file (`Print["hi"];2+2`) that works running in Command Prompt, how do I get it to run through IIS on Windows Server? It just comes up with a 404 not found. I have tried setting permissions on all users and application pools to be the same as the local server, and still nothing.